# Ajax call loading data only after first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET mvc project in which there is a feature to add comments. I want that on click of reply button, the create view gets loaded at space just after that particular comment. Reply() function is there for loading it. But the create view gets loaded in the space just after the very first comment, even if i click reply button below any comment. The below code is in ShowComments view, which i render at end of any other view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                //code to display other properties of comment object
                <section onclick="Reply()" class="btn btn-default">
                    Reply
                </section>
                <div id="ReplyCommentBox">

                </div>      
        }
```

Reply function has the following line

```
$('#ReplyCommentBox').load('http://localhost:5414/Comments/Create/');
```

Kindly help in figuring out a solution so that the create view gets loaded just after the comment for which reply button was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
            //code to display other properties of comment object
            <section class="btn btn-default reply-btn">
                Reply
            </section>
            <div class="ReplyCommentBox">

            </div>      
    }
```

in jQuery when you access elements by id, it gets the first element with the matching selector. That is the reason for adding to the first row always. in your case you have to use class instead of id as there are multiple elements of same class

```
$(document).on('click', '.reply-btn', function(){
    var replyBox = $(this).next('.ReplyCommentBox');
    var boxContent = $.trim(replyBox.html())

    if(boxContent){
        # if the `ReplyCommentBox` has content empty it
        replyBox.html('');
    }else{
        # no content, so load the div with content
        replyBox.load('http://localhost:5414/Comments/Create/');
    }
})
```

this will check if the `ReplyCommentBox` has any content in it. if it has any content, it will remove it else it will load the comment view.

Comment: Thanks Bhadra, but now nothing is happening on button click and console window is also not giving any error

Comment: Bhadra, still the same. Nothing happening on button click and no error on console.

Comment: can u check if the click function is getting called with the log in console. i have added a log in the click function can u debug and check if it is working or not?

Comment: No, there is no message in console

Comment: If i add the onclick=Reply() in section, then message is coming in console, but reply box still not loading.

Comment: can u check once. is this jquery loaded before the HTML code in DOM?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107702/discussion-between-bhadra-and-rachit-gupta).